# Swift, image from URL - Good quality on Ipad simulator, but very bad quality on Iphone 4s simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode6

I'm getting frustrated with this matter. Been trying to figure it out for few days with no avail.

The issue is very clear. I have an image view with fixed width and height 65x65px. I happen to have an image with the same dimensions (65x65px) on some web server.

What I'm doing is, loading the image of the URL into the image view. (will attach code below).

Everything works well, except quality of the images are VERY bad and I have no idea why. Tried all kind of things but can't seem to figure it out.

Will note that images loaded from image sets (locally) have very good quality (they don't have an issue. Only images from URLs have)

2 behaviors caught my attention:

1) If I make a button with width and height :65px, and put the image I fetch from URL as the button's BACKGROUND. its quality is perfect.

2) If I use bigger simulators, the quality becomes better and better. It's moderate (still abit bad) on Iphone 6 plus simulator, but almost perfect on Ipad/Ipad2

The code I'm using to fetch the image from URL and loading it into the ImageView is:

```
let imgUrl = NSURL(string: "http://imageurl")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgUrl!)
cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

I have tried all kind of desperate attempts, like trying with an imageview not in a table cell. Different images, different sizes, even setting the image as background which worked but I don't believe that's the solution...

I'm starting to think it's a simulator issue.. but I don't want to publish an app with such a problem (if it's not a simulator issue)

Another thing maybe worth mentioning but I doubt. I'm using a mac with remote access. Never tested this on the mac in front of me, but I doubt that's related, since other images which are local have great quality, and large simulators also have great quality.

Any input on the matter will be highly appreciated.

Regards.

EDIT: I'm using xCode 6.3.x

EDIT: After further investigating, I'm starting to guess it's a scaling/zoom issue. I think the issue is, when I open Iphone4s the images simply have zoom (the whole simulator window is zoomed in / scaled to fill the screen). I checked the "scale" on both Iphone4s and Ipad2 simulators, and it was 100% on both. However, the same image on Ipad2 is twice smaller than the same image on Iphone4S (on my screen), eventhough both have 65px width and height. So I suppose It IS a simulator issue? How can I be so sure though? or even know which version is the correct one.

EDIT:
It seems the problem is as stated above. The Iphone4S is not showing the real size of the images, it's like it's zoomed in. You can read the comments below for more information. Results of the test suggested by remus (Thank you very much for your help sir)

[image: Ipad2 Simulator]

[image: Iphone4S simulator]

Comment: No doubt you've seen my answer below - with your edits now, it's hard to be certain what's going on. Can you add a screenshot of the various simulators to your question? They do certainly scale differently. I do recommend you test by loading the image in **Mobile** Safari _on each device_ on each as well.

Comment: Nice one, will check that, and if I can conclude nothing I will take screen shots and upload to my question. Thank you

Comment: I believe your test has decided it. I'm uploading the screen shots. Indeed the images in mobile browser on both devices are different. Bad quality on Iphone4s. (looks like its zoomed in)

Comment: Your final judgement on the matter will be greatly appreciated. You can post it as an answer (or updated your existing one so I can approve it). Thank you again for your help and your test method suggestion.

Comment: Does your image host support SSL? If so, can you try again with https://?

Comment: It does not :( I can try with random image on the web though. Doing that now.

Comment: That's very interesting to me. I tried load multiple images over SSL and they are all looking good.. on Iphone4S, tried multiple other images not on SSL connection, and they look bad :O, I never knew something like this might be the case. Never faced this before.

Comment: Stands to reason then that it's probably related to your ISP. I'd look at finding a way to host the images over SSL :/

Comment: I'm renting this mac over the internet because I can't afford to stop working on the projects I'm currently on for few days. I don't believe this caused me to lose a lot of time haha, but well, these things just give us more experience, currently I haven't heard of any ISP that does anything similar here where I live, and the app is targeted locally, so I won't have to worry about that I suppose, but that piece of information will surely be stuck with me now :) Again I can't thank you enough for your help :) Best regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What country are you in / what service provider are you using? Several service providers will intercept graphics and lower their quality depending on the user agent. Try using SSL (`https://`) urls instead to prevent this from happening.

You can test this theory by loading the image url in Safari on all the devices and comparing them.

Comment: Hi Remus, first I have to say that I appreciate your reply a lot. Thank you for taking the time to give your input. However, I checked that and the quality is normal when I open the image in the browser (safari) on the remote mac. However, I updated my question with a second edit which I think is very close to figuring out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would have to be due to the retina display on the iPhone 4S. The iPad 2 does not have a retina display, so the image is displayed at its actual scale.

On the iPhone 4 (and above), the retina display is twice as dense, so it needs to scale the image by a factor of 2 to display it at the same size.

Try delivering a an image twice as large to the iPhone and you should see better results.

Comment: Hi Atreat, you think this might be the issue even after seeing the 2 images I uploaded through the simulator's safari browser? I mean if what you are saying is correct. I have to upload all images I use in my website for example to have double the size (and minimized) so they can be seen in good quality in apple phones?

Comment: when you use the iPhone 6 simulator or simulate any other device with a retina display what do you see?